# Pass the value to compile function in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make some generic field and use directive for that. For example, in HTML code I am defining:

```
<div def-field="name"></div>
<div def-field="surname"></div>
<div def-field="children"></div>
```

This field can be two types: either the simple element(as the first two) or a list of elements(as the third one). The scope variable contains the definition of all fields and their types.
For that I created the directive "def-field":

```
app.directive("defField", function($compile, $parse, $http) {
  restrict: 'A', // only for attributes
  scope : true,

  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only for attributes
    scope : true,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttributes) {

      //here I need to detect, which type of field is it.
      //if it is array, I need to execute the compile code      
      if(fieldType === 'array') {
        //execute secial code for compile furnction
      }

  }

  if(fieldType === 'array') {
    //return for array
    var returnValue = {pre : linkFunction};
  } else {
    //return for normal type
    var returnValue = {
       pre : linkFunction,
       post: function(scope, element, attrs){
         $compile(element.parent())(scope);
       }
     };
   }
  return returnValue;
}
```

The problem is that I need to get the fieldType from the scope variable and the scope variable is not available in the compile function. Is there is some possibility to workaround this issue?

Currently, I pass as an attribute the type "array", but for this is not an acceptable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some material about Angular, I have managed to find the solution. Unfortunately, in my application, the majority of business logic was in controllers, which is wrong according to style guides:

[Angular 1 Style Guide by John Papa (business logic)](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y035)

[Angular 1 Style Guide by Todd Motto (business logic)](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide#service-theory)

Therefore, I moved my business logic to controllers and then I was able to retrieve the required data in directive from service.
To show that, I have prepared a small demo example:

[Link to Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RZiXS4GeE487mN4Krqhq)

**Explanation of code:**
First, I defined a service, which should retrieve the required data:

```
(function () {

"use strict";

angular.module("dirExampleApp").service("directiveService", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {

        var self = this;

        self.getObjectData = function () {
            return $timeout(function () {

                var responseFromServer = {
                    firstName: {
                        value: "firstValue"
                    },
                    secondName: {
                        value: "secondValue"
                    },
                    thirdName: {
                        value: "thirdValue"
                    },
                    fourthName: {
                        value: "fourthValue"
                    }
                };
                self.content = responseFromServer;

            }, 300);
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Then, I can inject this service and use it in my directive in either *compile* or *prelink* or *postlink* functions:

```
(function () {

"use strict";
angular.module("dirExampleApp").directive("dirExample", ["$log", "directiveService", function ($log, directiveService) {

        return {
            restrict: "A",
            template: "<h3>Directive example!</h3>",
            compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
                var fieldName = tAttrs.dirExample;

                $log.log('Compile function: Field with name: ' + fieldName +
                        ' and sevice provided the following data: ' +
                        directiveService.content[fieldName].value);
                return {
                    pre: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                        var fieldName = iAttrs.dirExample;
                        $log.log('Prelink function: Field with name: ' + fieldName +
                                ' and sevice provided the following data: ' +
                                directiveService.content[fieldName].value);
                    },
                    post: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                        var fieldName = iAttrs.dirExample;
                        $log.log('Postlink function: Field with name: ' + fieldName +
                                ' and sevice provided the following data: ' +
                                directiveService.content[fieldName].value);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

    }]);

})();
```

As a result, there is some logging, when the directives are created. This logging demonstarates, that the required data has benn succesfully retrieved from service in *compile*, *prelink* and *postlink* functions of directive:

[image: Logging]

**Please note:** I am not sure, whether it is OK to use *service*, *factory* or *provider* for purpose of providing data. I only showed how it is possible with *service*. I guess, with *factory* and *provider*, the logic is the same.